# What determines if a data type is an object or a primitive data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have read that the `null` data type in JavaScript is a primitive data type, however due to a bug or something in the first version JavaScript, `null` is considered to be an object.

However, let's assume that `null` is a real object (and not a primitive data type like it really is), what does that mean exactly, i.e. what does a data type being an object mean exactly?

For example if a data type is an object, does that mean that attributes and methods can be added to instances of that data type, while a primitive data type can't have attributes and methods added to its instances? and so the reasosn why `null` is really a primitive data type and not an object is because you can't add attributes and methods to its instances?

Comment: [Here's the list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive); the way to know is to remember the list.

Comment: In JS, all primitives have in common that all values of any primitive type are always immutable. Only objects are not always immutable, so they’re not considered primitives. Properties can, in theory, exist on primitives — notably Records, which will become part of the language in the future.